# Multiple OpenGL windows on Windows, sharing context

Tags: windows, opengl, multiple-monitors

I'm trying to setup multiple OpenGL (3.3) windows on the same program. I've created 2 windows, with the second one having the shared context of the first one (using hglrc[i] = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(hdc[n_windows], hglrc[0], ctxattribs) while the first one has 0 instead of hglrc[0]), with a simple loop like:

```
for(unsigned i = 0; i < n_windows; ++i)
{
    wglMakeCurrent(hdc[i], hglrc[i]);
    glClearColor((float)rand() / RAND_MAX, (float)rand() / RAND_MAX, (float)rand() / RAND_MAX, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    SwapBuffers(hdc[i]);
}
```

However only one window renders, and when I move a window to another screen, the Window that wasn't rendering now renders, and the other one stops rendering.

It's the first time I'm trying to open several OpenGL windows on the same application, with a shared context, so I might be doing something wrong. My code works perfectly with one window, and my old faithful gDEBugger doesn't show any error. Any idea on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Are your two windows being serviced by the same GPU?

Comment: Since you're obviously not using multithreading, why don't you simply use a single OpenGL context for all the windows (i.e. have only one single hglrc)? This is perfectly valid to do. Also SwapBuffers is independent of OpenGL; unfortunately there's no SwapBuffers variant that takes an array of DCs, to synchronize the buffer swaps of several windows (that's where I resort to multithreading, each thread doing a SwapBuffers – total waste of resources, but you can't do it differently – AFAIK).

Comment: I didn't realise it was possible to share a single hglrc. I'll try that to see if it works.